# Jquery UI: Want effect when not accepted draggable is 'dropped' on droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm not familiar with jquery ui in depth and didn't find a solution for the following simple setting:
I have a gallery with different kinds of waste and two trash cans, one for paper and one for 'bio'. When the user drags #waste_1 and drops it on #paper everything is ok, because .paper is accepted in #paper.
**In case that** the user drags #waste_2 and drops it on #paper **it should revert and #paper should shake**. Revert works fine but I didn't find a way to detect the droppable when the waste is not accepted.
The structure (simplified):

```
<ul class="waste">
   <li id="waste_1" class="paper"></li>
   <li id="waste_2" class="bio"></li>
</ul>

<div class="trashcan">
   <div id="bio" class="bio"></div>
   <div id="paper" class="paper"></div>
</div>
```

In other words: I need a way to detect the droppable, where the dropped waste 'reverted from'.
I hope my question is understandable and I would be grateful for any advice.